# phpmyadmin error: #1062 - Duplicate Entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' on all databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

On any database in PHPMyAdmin, if I select a table, select structure, and select change to any column I receive the following error:

> error: #1062 - Duplicate Entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

The error doesn't stop me from making changes, it doesn't stop me from inserting data...doesn't really do anything but show up every time.

Note there are no duplicate keys and the error appears on tables with and without data. It appeared today on the database that were not changed (such as the PHPMyAdmin database) and did not have the error earlier. 
I've restarted xampp and my computer.

Before I continue making changes and adding data, I'd really like to solve this. Thank you in advance and let me know what other info you need.

Comment: there are no duplicates because you get the error message. So you have to checkl the source code of your inserts, where you sent a double insert to the server. If you can't find anything, yu must enabke at least temporary the logging of all query, to see  which comes double, and find so the source.

Comment: I enabled the general_log table but I'm not quiet sure what I'm looking for. Am I looking for a repeating logs?

Comment: look for insert in your table and then there must be a double entry. and in php you must enter debug code to see what is running twice